# How to show a trimmed version of the report?

Tags: nodes, users

When a user has access to a report, that report becomes user specific. But, how to show a trimmed version of the same report to other users?

I have used [content access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) and [ACL](http://drupal.org/project/acl) module to give per user access.